# Why is this text going out of the div bounds

Tags: css

I'm not sure what is going on here. I've tried changing the display, position, width and max width of both elements.
How do I get this text to make a new line on its own?

[image: Element]

[image: Parent]

Comment: After removing nowrap, the next line ignores the left padding, is this normal?

Comment: No, but you want left padding then you can add "left-padding: 1rem;" to the "g" class

Comment: It's not working T_T

Comment: Plese add the code here, i will give you solution if any bug exist

Comment: there is a lot...

Comment: But it just images, i can not update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have added  `white-space: nowrap` for `g` please remove it or add `white-space: normal`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not wrapping now because of the `white-space: nowrap` rule. Try removing or overriding that.